# Connect to Oracle OnPremises using Azure Data Factory - via S2sVPN

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-data-factory, linked-service

Is it possible to connect to on-premises Oracle DB using Azure Data Factory via a Site to Site VPN? Or am I obliged to use a Self-Hosted Integration Runtime?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your data store is located inside an on-premises network, an Azure virtual network, or Amazon Virtual Private Cloud, you need to configure a self-hosted integration runtime to connect to it.

If your data store is a managed cloud data service, you can use the Azure Integration Runtime. If the access is restricted to IPs that are approved in the firewall rules, you can add Azure Integration Runtime IPs to the allow list.

You can also use the managed virtual network integration runtime feature in Azure Data Factory to access the on-premises network without installing and configuring a self-hosted integration runtime.

For more information about the network security mechanisms and options supported by Data Factory, see [Data access strategies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-access-strategies).

The integration runtime provides a built-in Oracle driver. Therefore, you don't need to manually install a driver when you copy data from and to Oracle.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle?tabs=data-factory